# How to set the background color of all windows in xaml C#?

Tags: c#

Is there an easy way to set the background color of all windows in app.xaml?
I hope to set the default background color of windows in app.xaml.
Please let me know how to set the background color of all windows in xaml.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default styles in App.xaml file like that:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

**TargetType** is looking for specific type of element, For example Gird, Button, DockPanel

**Property** is specifying exact value you want to set

**Value** is the value itself